# Run a script as root upon user login into XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, startup, root

I am setting up a "special" environment for user `john` on my workstation running `XFCE` desktop. When `john` signs I want to tweak system configuration which requires `root` access. I am looking for a way to run a script as root upon user signing into `XFCE` which would check user name and make tweaks as necessary.

My research led me to the idea of putting my script in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` and use `session-setup-script`. But am not sure if it is the right place. I need an advice from a guru.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out a working solution just the way I need it.

I created a file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/kids.conf` with content

```
[Seat:*]
session-setup-script=/root/bin/tweak-sys-config.sh
```

`tweak-sys-config.sh` runs as `root` only once (unlike `.profile` that may run many times) upon desktop user singin with `$USER` environment variable initialized to user login.